# Change FPS when creating gif from pictures with ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg

I'm trying to create a gif from a set of pictures with ffmpeg; currently i'm using:

```
ffmpeg -i <input images> <output-file>.gif
```

Which works perfect, but i would like to know how can i change the frame ratio of the created gif? (meaning, how much time for the delay between two frames)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Add `ffmpeg -framerate N -i <input images> <output-file>.gif`

Comment: Tried that already, it doesn't recognize the flag (im in osx)

Comment: Then your ffmpeg is old.

Comment: You were right, reinstalled it and worked, thanks!